# Is there a "should" minitest gem?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest, expectations, fluent-assertions

I would like to use fluent assertions type of syntax with minitest

```
result.should_be "my result"
result.should_be_true
result.should_contain "foo"
```

Is there some gem that adds this functionality?

My request come from a [similar idea in C#](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/documentation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minitest already comes with its own module for this kind of assertions, it is [Minitest::Expectations](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Expectations.html)

```
result.must_equal 'my result'
result.must_equal true
result.must_include 'foo'
result.wont_include 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

`rspec` adds this assertion type, you can check out the gem here: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails